# Set a textView in a different layout to the value of an EditText

Tags: java, android, button, layout, textview

I'm making an app and I am trying to make a settings panel where all of your data from signing up is stored.  I have a change button next to a TextView and when you click on that it takes you to a page called email where you can change your email you signed up with.  There is an EditText and in the code I have a string that stores the data of what is in the EditText.  It is supposed to set the email text to the EditText and go back to the settings page. But it goes back to the settings page and the email stays the same.

Code:

```
private TextView SetEmail;
private Button ChangeEmail;
private EditText newEmail;
private Button Save;
ChangeEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
   setContentView(R.layout.email);
   newEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EmailChange);
   Save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Save);
   emailerror = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emailerror);



   Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
   String newEmails = newEmail.getText().toString();
   String Text = SetEmail.getText().toString();


   if (newEmails.contains("@") && newEmails.contains(".com") || newEmails.contains(".net") || newEmails.contains(".global")) {

SetEmail.setText(newEmails);

setContentView(R.layout.settings);

} else {
emailerror.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                    }
```

Thank you for helping me out

p.s. I am working in one class.

Comment: when you are returning to settings page, most likely you are not setting the text again for TextView using current value.

Comment: It would help if you posted code.

Comment: I'm saying that if the EditText meets certain requirements than set the text to the EditText value and change the layout to settings.

Comment: I Posted Code in my question

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your "*page called email*" is a different Activity, so you open that Activity using "startActivityForResult()" and when you want to close that "email Activity" you have to execute "setResult(resultCode, Intent)".

Link: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result